# Why does a term dissappear in my equation when changing lines?

Tags: math-mode, equations

I have the following code in an overleaf latex environment:

```
\begin{equation}
\centering
 h_+ = \frac{G}{rc^4}[\ddot{M}_{11}(cos^2\phi - sin^2\phi cos^2\theta)+ \\ 
 + \ddot{M}_{22}(sin^2\phi - cos^2\phi cos^2\theta )- \ddot{M}_{33}sin^2\theta -\ddot{M}_{12}sin2\phi (1+cos^2\theta)+\ddot{M}_{13}sin\phi sin2\theta +\ddot{M}_{23}cos\phi sin2\theta ] 
\caption{h+ for arbitrary direction with quadrupole moment analysis}
\label{h+m}
\end{equation}
```

and I need to fit it into the page. So I need to break it somewhere. But no matter what I try, changing the line results in "eating" the `\ddot{M}` leaving only its indices (22).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with fixing the errors:

- no blank line is allowed inside math displays;
- `\centering` has no effect whatsoever;
- line breaks aren't possible inside `equation`;
- `\caption` cannot be part of `equation`.

You get

1. six errors `Missing $ inserted`
2. two errors `Display math should end with $$`
3. one error `` You can't use `\eqno' in vertical mode ``
4. one error `There's no line here to end`
5. one error `\caption outside float`

The errors in 1, 2 ad 3 are due to the blank lines inside equation; the errors in 4 and 5 should be self-explanatory. Never disregard error messages: the output you get is essentially arbitrary rubbish deriving from the attempts of TeX at error recovery.

The sine and cosine functions should be `\sin` and `\cos`. You also need more lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

The standard way would be to present the equation for
$h+$ for arbitrary direction with quadrupole moment analysis
\begin{equation}\label{eq:h+m}
\begin{aligned}
h_+ = \frac{G}{rc^4}[
  &  \ddot{M}_{11}(\cos^2\phi - \sin^2\phi \cos^2\theta)
   + \ddot{M}_{22}(\sin^2\phi - \cos^2\phi \cos^2\theta)
  \\
  &- \ddot{M}_{33}\sin^2\theta
   - \ddot{M}_{12}\sin2\phi (1+\cos^2\theta)
  \\
  &+ \ddot{M}_{13}\sin\phi \sin2\theta
   + \ddot{M}_{23}\cos\phi \sin2\theta ] 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
with the text announcing what the equation is about
when the equation is presented.

If you really want, you can use a caption in the
\texttt{figure} environment. In this case an equation
number is just confusing.

\begin{figure}[!htp]

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
h_+ = \frac{G}{rc^4}[
  &  \ddot{M}_{11}(\cos^2\phi - \sin^2\phi \cos^2\theta)
   + \ddot{M}_{22}(\sin^2\phi - \cos^2\phi \cos^2\theta)
  \\
  &- \ddot{M}_{33}\sin^2\theta
   - \ddot{M}_{12}\sin2\phi (1+\cos^2\theta)
  \\
  &+ \ddot{M}_{13}\sin\phi \sin2\theta
   + \ddot{M}_{23}\cos\phi \sin2\theta ] 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\caption{$h+$ for arbitrary direction with quadrupole moment analysis}
\label{h+m}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Beware that figures can float, so I recommend the first way.

Comment: the caption is needed for the appendix and it's part of the equation mode in the overleaf guide. And there aren't any error messages. It doesn't give me any

Comment: at least & worked. with aligned anyway. it wasn't working with align. thank you

Comment: @AgathaHarkness The `\caption` command doesn't work everywhere. It requires specific environments to have any effect, typically environments that make their content float.